# Background of Eclipse's method list description panel is black

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 on my system and am using OpenJDK. When I installed the Java Eclipse IDE, everything seemed to work fine at first until I started a project. When the method/variable list appears, it looks fine except that the panel giving you information on the method has a black background with white text. I want to change that back to black text on white, but my search through the preferences turned up nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a setting that you have to change in Gnome. I don't have Ubuntu installed currently, so the solution is from my memory, and maybe the menu entries are named a bit differently:
Go to System Settings -> Appearance. Then you have somewhere a button to change colors, and there is somewhere an entry for tooltips, which is black. Change that and the color setting for the font.